# Check if DB is available

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel

I need to check if a postgres db is available.

If the db is online, I get the timestamp.

If the db is offline, I get a laravel PDO Exception

But every time I get a Exception and the script execution stops

```
try
{
    $con = new PDO("pgsql:host=".$db->Host.";port=".$db->Port.";dbname=postgres", $db->Username, $db->Password, [PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT => '5']);

    $dt = new \DateTime(null, new \DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin'));

    return $dt->getTimestamp();
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    return false;       
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    return false;       
}
```

Comment: `echo $e->getMessage()` will show you error text.

Comment: Do you mean your try...catch doesnt work?

Comment: The error message is, that they cannot connect to the server.
But I want to get a false back, now I get a Laravel Error page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to prepend `\` infront of the exceptions:

```
try
{
    $con = new PDO("pgsql:host=".$db->Host.";port=".$db->Port.";dbname=postgres", $db->Username, $db->Password, [PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT => '5']);

    $dt = new \DateTime(null, new \DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin'));

    return $dt->getTimestamp();
}
catch(\Exception $e)
{
    return false;       
}
```

Comment: It couldn't find the Exception in your namespace

Comment: I thought the PDOException is in the same namespace like PDO

Comment: I'm not sure where the PDOException lies but you checked the generic Exception first, so it wont go in there anyways. But try to only add the PDOException if you still catch it.